# How to keep package versions in sync between Packaging Project and regular versions

Tags: c#, .net-core, uwp

I had an dotnet core app, which had version number set via: `/p:Version=$(Build_Version)`, and then retrieved via `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version`.

Recently I've added windows packaging project, to let users take advantage of automiatic update via `.appinstaller` files, however they have separate versioning via `.appxmanifest`. I want to keep old way of working with package as exe, ie. for portable scenarios.

Looks like `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current` works only for packaged project, and I do not see easy way to set `/p:Version=$(Build_Version)` while building packaged project.

How can I keep uniform way of setting and retrieving versions of my app?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `Version` can be specified when building `wapproj`, however it is separate from `ApplicationVersion`. This is command which worked for me:
`msbuild MyProj.wapproj /p:Configuration=Release;AppxBundle=Always;AppxBundlePlatforms="x64";Platform=x64;Version=1.0.0.0;ApplicationVersion=1.0.0.0`

Then I can ignore `Package.Current` version and just use assembly vesion.